# Envers configuration in hibernate 3.5.5 using Spring

Tags: hibernate

So we have a Spring file so, we are using Hibernate-3.5.5

class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

```
<value>Run.hbm.xml

</value>
```

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">${dialect}</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">

 <!--  org.hibernate.cache.ehcacheprovider-->

 net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider

</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">

 true

</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>



<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

         <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">_Audit</prop>

         <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name">REV</prop>

         <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name">REVTYPE</prop>

         <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.default_schema">SQN_OWN</prop>

            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_on_collection_change">false</prop>
```

```
<entry key="post-insert">

 <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />

</entry>

<entry key="post-update">

 <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />

</entry>

<entry key="post-delete">

 <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />

</entry>

<entry key="pre-collection-update">

 <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />

</entry>

<entry key="pre-collection-remove">

 <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />

</entry>

<entry key="post-collection-recreate">

 <bean class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />

</entry>
```

When I start up the application I am getting the error HibernateException could not init listeners. After debugging further, The error comes from AuditConfiguration class at :

AudiConfiguration(Configuration C){

Properties properties = cfg.getProperties();

ReflectionManager reflectionManager = ((AnnotationConfiguration) cfg).getReflectionManager(); failing on classCastException cfg is not an instance of  AnnotationConfiguration ..

What could I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this was that in the constructor of AuditConfiguration the configuration typed cast to 
AnnotationConfiguration. Using this spring context snippet, seems to have the problem resolved.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"

    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="namingStrategy">
        <ref bean="namingStrategy" />
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
```